# Did George Bailey build the homes in Bailey Park?

Tags: its-a-wonderful-life

In the Christmas classic film [*It's a Wonderful Life* (1946)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038650/), the main character, George Bailey, gives up his dream of traveling and going to college to become an architect so that he can help others in various ways, primarily by continuing his father's legacy of running a local building and loan firm.

One of the things that George does to help turn around the Bailey Building and Loan and make it more profitable is to purchase some cheap land and develop it into a neighborhood of affordable homes called Bailey Park.

As I rewatched the film this year, something Clarence says hit me. George and Clarence go to Bailey Park but it's not there because George hadn't been born.

> **George:** All I know is this should be Bailey Park. But where are the houses?
>
> **Clarence:** You weren't here to build them.

It struck me that I had never considered that George had literally built the houses himself, or at least been involved in their architecture, as an outlet for his dream of becoming an architect.

But did Clarence mean that he literally built them or simply that he was responsible for them being built? Is there any other evidence in the movie that George actually architected or physically built the homes in Bailey Park?

Comment: I doubt George literally built them. He likely hired a development contractor through his business. He likely designed the place, though, as you said an outlet for his penchant for architecture. Then through the Building and Loan business, he provided loans at affordable rates for these affordable homes so people could move out of Potter’s rental slums.